# wxPython using a sizer with panels

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to make a GUI with on the left side a camera input with some data on the camera stream. On the right side I want some buttons and other widgets. The code a have so far: (the functions `get_image()` and `pil_to_wx()` work fine, they're just not shown in the code below)

```
class HUDPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(HUDPanel, self).__init__(parent, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.Refresh()
        self.Update()
        wx.CallLater(15, self.update)

    def create_bitmap(self):
        image = get_image()
        bitmap = pil_to_wx(image)
        return bitmap

    def on_paint(self, event):
        bitmap = self.create_bitmap()
        dc = wx.AutoBufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0)


class ExtraPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ExtraPanel, self).__init__(parent, -1)
        My_Button = wx.Button(self,label="TEST")


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wx.RESIZE_BORDER & ~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None, -1, 'Camera Viewer', style=style)

        my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        campanel = HUDPanel(self)
        my_sizer.Add(campanel, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        widgetpanel = ExtraPanel(self)
        my_sizer.Add(widgetpanel, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(my_sizer)


        self.Fit()


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this code, all I get is a small window with only a button named "TEST" (the panel that should be on the right side). The previous version with only the camera panel worked fine, so that's not the problem. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
The sizes of the sub-panels are fixed, i see the panel with the camera show up but only a small line on the screen. The part with the button show perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't give any size to your `HUDPanel`, so I'm not sure how do you expect it to appear.

Second, you're recursively calling `update` all the time (well every 15ms), which is most definitely a bad idea as this will consume close to 100% of (one) CPU and may prevent your application from dispatching other events.

Comment: I've added `self.SetSize((640,480))` to `HUDPanel` and the same to `ExtraPanel` (to make sure they have the same size). and I added a size twice as broad to my main frame, to make sure that both the panels have enough space to show up, but only the panel with the button shows.

Comment: You should create it with size or call `SetInitialSize()` if you want it to not shrink under it, calling `SetSize()` later doesn't prevent the window from becoming smaller (otherwise its size could never decrease!).

Comment: adding `self.SetInitialSize()` worked out just fine, thank you for your help!